# Apple Mid 2012 VGA vs Apple retina late 2013 VGA onboard

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd, vga-adapter

I'm trying to buy a new mac book. I have two choices: one is Apple Macbook Pro retina mid 2012 with NVIDIA GeForce GT 650M 1024 MB. And another is new macbook late retina 2013 using VGA onboard.

I have googled but found no answer for comparison between those graphics. Does NVIDIA Graphics card is really stronger than core i5 VGA onboard (gen 4) ?

@: sub question: about SSD, I see some benchmark, and see that SSD on 2013 is faster than SSD on 2012. Does this true ?

Thanks :)

Comment: are you playing heavy duty graphics games ?

Comment: No. i just use graphic software design often. such as Photoshop. AI. Unity ... :)

Answer (score 1):

I found out [here that the difference](http://www.game-debate.com/gpu/index.php?gid=1783&gid2=832&compare=iris-pro-graphics-5200-mobile-vs-geforce-gt-650m-gddr5) is very minor in gaming performances.

[image: comparison]

Not to mention that the NVIDIA is a add on device while the Intel is integrated,resulting in more power consumption and graphics mode switching--that you might not want.

Comment: thanks :) so it looks like intel makes vga onboard so good :) can you tell me about ssd part. does 2013 line will faster than 2012. thanks :)

Comment: Actually it looks like Intel will severely damage the NVIDA business if they continue this road of superior GPU designs.

Comment: Yes it does read/write faster due to the SSD connector technology change from (SATA to PCIe).

Comment: except that, are there any differences in SSD technology, or all of ssd part uses same technology ? thanks :)

Comment: sorry, could you ask that as a new question, something like what is the SSD technology differences on Mac models, since the comments here are not meant for extended discussions